# upload_max_filesize not reflected in phpinfo()

Tags: php, linux, apache, ini

In my php.ini file (there is only one on the system) I have

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 8M
upload_max_size = 8M
```

Originally they were set to 2M. I changed them to 8M restarted apache, even restarted instance. But when I do a phpinfo() on it, it still shows 2M.

I am pretty sure I have the right php.ini file because if I increase the max_execution_time it is reflected in the phpinfo() but anything I put in for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size is not reflected in phpinfo() even though I double check php.ini and the settings are there.

This is a AWS Linux instance. 
php5.2.16
apache 2.2.17(EL)

Any thoughts from the guru’s out there?

Comment: Is your `phpinfo()` confirming that it is actually using the right php.ini? It should say so in the first or second paragraph IIRC

Comment: Yes. When I do a phpinfo() it shows the php.ini to be in /etc/php.ini (which is the one i am modifying)

Comment: Additionally ini files can get parsed, some of those are not listed in the pnpinfo() output. Read the ini section in the manual carefully, it's documented where all those settings can come from.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have entries in Apache's `.htaccess` file that are overwriting the options?

They would look something like:

```
php_flag post_max_size 2M
php_flag upload_max_filesize 2M
php_flag upload_max_size 2M
```

Here's Apache's `.htaccess` documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: I double-checked the .htaccess and there are no overrides in there like you described :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a local server, such as wamp or xampp, make sure it's using the php.ini you think it is.  These servers usually default to a php.ini that's not in your html docs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your php.ini file don't have any errors. php.ini takes all default values after error line.

I was having same issue, I fixed after removing errors from php.ini.

Hope this help.